# React, set a new state value but not apply directly

Tags: reactjs

I have two function, one for retrieve filters and format it in object, and one when table page change.
The problem is when i set a new state in the handle page change function, when i call the function to get filters in the same function it is not working.

My code :

```
const getFilters = () => {
        var filters = [
            {'name': 'settlements.from_date', 'value': startDate.getFullYear()+'-'+(startDate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+startDate.getDate()},
            {'name': 'settlements.to_date', 'value': endDate.getFullYear()+'-'+(endDate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+endDate.getDate()},
            {'name': 'datatable|per_page', 'value': perPage },
            {'name': 'datatable|page', 'value': page },
        ];

        if(isPaid != "all") {
            filters = [
                ...filters,
                {'name': 'is_paid#having', 'value': isPaid}
            ];
        }

        if(partner != "all") {
            filters = [
                ...filters,
                {'name': 'settlements.partners_id', 'value': partner}
            ];
        }

        return filters;
    }

    const handlePageChange = page => {
        console.log('page : '+page);
        setPage(page);
        console.log(getFilters());
    };
```

In the function handlePageChange, the console log for page equals to the new value, but the console log for getFilters echo the past value (-1).

Someone had idea ?

Comment: You need to use useEffect to get the setState changes. But i wonder why dont you simply pass the page value to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous): **State Updates May Be Asynchronous**

This means that your call to `setPage` will not immediately update the state, but React will wait until the next re-render until the new state is usable.

Put the `console.log(getFilters());` in a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook, with the `page` variable as a dependency, and you will see the console log after each time that state change has been applied.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is working perfectly. And I must not forget that it is possible to have several useEffect in one component.

Comment: Yeah! Just see them as things that only get called when something in that dep-array is changed, otherwise they don't get used